# Unity - persistence with inspector-added references

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, initialization, persistence

I have a persistent `game object` that I use to initialize basically everything. The script `Persistence` as I call it has some `public` references I just dragged on them via the inspector. 
I'm trying to make it persistent like I found online:

```
public static Persistence instance;
void Awake()
{
    if (instance != null)
    {
        DestroyImmediate(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

The thing is, when I load a level from main menu, it's fine. When I load back the main menu from that level, it says

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Persistence' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

So I decided to let it create other instances when loading the main menu, but that messes up all the scripts on the game levels that rely on this data.

My question is, how to correctly implement this ~singleton persistent pattern in Unity, given I have inspector-added references?

**NOTE** that I initialize only from my `Awake` function in my persistent class and from nowhere else. Literally, my `InitializeMe` scripts are called from the `Persistence` class, one after the other.

What should I do differently to make this work? Initialize from a different, non-persistent `gameobject`? Forget dragging to the inspector? Any advice to make this work is appreciated.

Comment: `if instance, instance = this`? That's not valid c# code

Comment: you tell me, I found it online. Though I found an `instance = this` in an official Unity tutorial as well :/

Comment: `instance = this` is correct (while weird and only for singletons), but for `if (instance)` to work, `instance` should be *implicitly* convertible to `bool` and `MonoBehavior` is not

Comment: should it be `instance != null` ?

Comment: even if so, the problem is persistent (haha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. So here's the thing one should know (I should have known) before messing around with persistence in Unity:

> You don't drag references to a persistent GO via the inspector as they are gone the instant another scene is loaded except for additive loading. Also the persistent GO may hold data relevant to multiple scenes, hold functionality that is built for general purpose, as reusable as it goes, but it never initializes anything itself or interfere with non-persistent GOs other than being called - used as a tool - or providing the data.

This arcane wisdom is mine though, so anyone more skilled reading this, please do correct me if I'm wrong before others take this to heart.

So to be exact, I made a non-persistent master `INITIALIZER` that does the exact thing. I get all the scene GOs into a collection **once** and no `GameObject.Find` again. I used LINQ queries to conveniently filter my results from that collection. Another thing was my `InitializeMe` abstract class (or to be more precise, its descendants).

```
public abstract class InitializeMe : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int orderNumber;
    public abstract void INIT(INITIALIZER init);
}
```

here orderNumber is used to determine the order of the initializations, should one object depend on the other. It also worths mentioning that doing like so can result in a **very** predictable way to setting things up, as it is done one after the other. Note that this doesn't create a bottleneck, because Unity's scripting API only be executed in the main thread - dividing the code into multiple `Awake` or `Start` methods wouldn't perform better to my best knowledge as of 2017. It is used by a LINQ query in the `INITIALIZER`.
The good thing in `INITIALIZER` is that - again - it holds itself *everything*, including a reference to the persistent object and the save data as well, so via referencing itself to the `InitializeMe` methods they can do everything they need - as `DataBank` provides general purpose tools with persistent data, and `INITIALIZER` provides volatile (hope I use that right, I mean relevant to only main menu) data with some additional functionality that is used only for the main menu.

Now, persistence was ensured not by the persistent class itself, but by this `INITIALIZER` in `Awake` like so:

```
//find by tag or rename upon instantiation as by doing so will result in a "(Clone)" added to its name.
var d = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("DataBank");
if (d == null)
{
    //instantiating it
    DATA = GameObject.Instantiate<DataBank>(DATA_blueprint);
    //intializing the databank itself. The parameters are needed for me,
    // but serve as a good example - all of those are dragged from the inspector to the _INITIALIZER_ but will remain in the whole game as long as databank exists.
    DATA.LoadDataFromINIT(_baseColor, _baseColor2, _outlineColor,
           new MMtoolBundle(DATA));
    //to make it persistent.
    DontDestroyOnLoad(DATA);
}else
{
    //in this case the main menu is loaded from another scene.
    //so we only find that loaded object and get its reference, no initialization as it was already setup.
    this.DATA = d.GetComponent<DataBank>();
}
```

where `DATA` is my persistent `DataBank`. Note that by default I have **NO DataBank** object on the scene. `DATA_blueprint` is the prefab of `DataBank` dragged by the inspector (as `INITIALIZER` is not persistent). It could be loaded via `AssetDatabase` as well but this was a bit more convenient.

it worths mentioning that while `DataBank` is a `MonoBehaviour` itself so it can appear in Unity scenes, none of its members are `MonoBehaviour`s so it is possible to harness the power of inheritance. Should one wish to start a `coroutine` in a non-mono toolkit, it would have to be started with a reference from `DataBank` itself.

An obvious drawback of this method is that the existence of my persistent GO depends on `INITIALIZER`, so that one has to be on the first scene. But again, as most games start with a main menu, this shouldn't pose a big issue (talking about single player games).

**YET AGAIN** I would recommend someone more skilled to correct me in case I lead others astray, but this solution worked for me - got the same and only persistent GO in all my scenes with no other ever created.